# Como encontrar a enésima ocorrência de uma substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Preciso fazer uma função que recebe como entrada uma string, uma letra, e um número que indica a
ocorrência desejada da letra (1 para primeira ocorrência, 2 para segunda, etc).

A função precisa retornar
em que posição da string aquela ocorrência da letra está.

Caso exista menos ocorrências da letra do que
a ocorrência pedida, a função deve retornar -1.

Exemplo: (”mariana come banana”,’a’,3).
Resposta: 6 (posição da terceira ocorrência da letra ’a’ na string dada)

Tentativa:

```
    def posLetra(string,letra,n):
        i=0
        indice=0
        while i<len(string):
            x=str.find(string,letra)
            indice=indice+x
            i=i+0
        return indice
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função builtin [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) que devolve uma lista tuplas contendo uma contagem do iteravel passado como parâmetro onde em cada tupla o índice 0 é o posição do elemento no iterável e o índice 1 é o próprio elemento.

```
#t é o texto, l é a letra e n é número da ocorrência a ser pesquisada
def posLetra(t, l, n):
    correncias = []                  #Lista em que serão salvas as posições de cada ocorrencia de l
    for c in enumerate(t):           #Para cada tupa c na enumeração de t...
        if c[1] == l:                ##...se o caractere enumerado for igual a l...
            correncias.append(c[0])  ##...adiciona sua posição na lista de correncias.
    if n >= len(correncias):         #Se a ocorrência a se pesquisada for maior que a quantidade de ocorrência encontradas...
        return -1                    #...retorna -1.
    return correncias[n - 1]         #Retorna a ocorrência n.
```

O mesmo código acima usando [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) e [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
def posLetra(t, l, n):
    correncias = [c[0] for c in enumerate(t) if c[1] == l]
    return -1 if n >= len(correncias) else correncias[n - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência que encontrar, mas é possível passar como parâmetro a posição a partir da qual a busca é feita.

Ou seja, basta chamar `find` várias vezes, usando a posição anterior como referência para a próxima busca:

```
def find_nth(texto, busca, n):
    pos = texto.find(busca)
    while pos >= 0 and n > 1:
        pos = texto.find(busca, pos + 1)
        n -= 1
    return pos
 
print(find_nth('mariana come banana', 'a', 3)) # 6
print(find_nth('mariana', 'a', 10)) # -1
```

O `while` prossegue até que se encontre a n-ésima ocorrência, ou até `find` retornar `-1` (o que indica que não há mais ocorrências).